# How to get information using CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I tried to use CSS in scrapy shell: `response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get()`

response: `'\xa0'` . how to remove it?

```html
<td class="answer">
  <table class="answer-options">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

**scraper.py**

```
def profile(self, response):
    yield {'Company Name': response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get()}
```

Comment: can you try `response.replace('\xa0', '')` ?

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'url'

Comment: I meant
`var = response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get()` and then var.replace('\xa0', '')

Comment: so can i use?
'response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get().replace('\xa0', '')'

Comment: What if response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get() is None then you will get error NoneType doesnt have method replace so better to do it separately.

Comment: please tell me how to check in yield. for each respose to call a variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60728855/2286762 will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- since &nbsp is basically a fancy whitespace you could use `.strip()` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
- if there is nothing that fits the CSS selector you'll get `None` as your `Company Name`. That would result in error if you add strip like `.get().strip()`. Consider checking for `None` first:

  ```
  def profile(self, response):
      out = response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get()
      if out is not None:
          yield {'Company Name': out.strip()}
  ```

Edit: you seem to have multiple fieds with different `#fq` index. You could group names and indices before parsing, that would allow you to use a loop:

```
def profile(self, response):
    fields = {
        'field1': 1,
        'field3': 3,
        'Company Name': 9
    }
    for name in fields:
        value = response.css('#fq{} .answer-options td::text'.format(fields[name])).get()
        if value is not None:
            yield {name: value.strip()}
```

Comment: How to check multiple fields at once? use for?

'def profile(self, response):
        Company_Name = response.css('#fq9 .answer-options td::text').get()
        if Company_Name is not None:
            Company_Name = Company_Name.strip()
        Anesthesiologists_Name = response.css('#fq14 .answer-options td::text').get()
        if  Anesthesiologists_Name is not None:
            Anesthesiologists_Name = Anesthesiologists_Name.strip()
        yield {
                'Company Name': Company_Name,
                'Anesthesiologists Name': Anesthesiologists_Name,
                }'

Comment: Seems like you have an index: fq id with number. First generate css selectors, then use for loop for everything

Comment: I updated my answer with example for multiple fields